# Rails: Return Records Where Array of IDs for Associated Model All Exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, join

So I have a model of goals and for each goal there are skaters on the ice when it is scored.  I want to return the goals where specific combinations of skaters were on for a goal.  The relationship looks like so:

```
class Goal < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :on_ice_skaters
end

class OnIceSkater < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :goal
end
```

I've been trying to do it via a .joins then a .where but it seems to return goals where ANY of the players in the array were present and not when ALL were present (each OnIceSkater record has a player_id):

```
player_ids = [6382,5635]
Goal.joins(:on_ice_skaters).where('on_ice_skaters.player_id' => player_ids)
```

Was wondering if there was a way to turn the above statement into an AND statement functionally (eg. Find Goals that have OnIceSkaters with player_id 6382 AND 5635)?

Answer (score 0):

If you write two `.where()` clauses in a row, ActiveRecord `AND`s them together. So try this:

```
player_ids = [6382,5635]
goals = Goal.joins(:on_ice_skaters)

player_ids.each do |player_id|
  goals = goals.where(on_ice_skaters: { player_id: player_id })
end
```

I took the liberty of upgrading your string to a hash. It might be more accurate, and it certainly looks more Railsey.

Comment: Just wondering if this will cause the where method call to execute every time the expression in the loop is run. Is there a way to chain them up first and then send in an _execute_

Comment: @manu29.d try passign the array to where: `goals.where(on_ice_skaters: {player_id: player_ids})`

Comment: @maxpleaner But that will just become the problem statement again. That wasn't my consideration. I was thinking if there was a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: ActiveRecord is lazy and will not execute anything until you need it, so the query is not executed until you actually access the data.

Comment: @Iceman But look at the `each` loop. The value _is_ being used in the next iteration.

Comment: It is lazily loaded, just try it. The value is not being used, this is the Rails way of building an sql query.

Comment: However, I don't think this query will behave in the way you're hoping it does. Each row of `OnIceSkater.player_id` can only match with one id, not many. You will need some subquery I suspect.

Comment: So the first .where statement works as it should but the following ones return no results (I did go through by hand and check if there should have been matches).  @Iceman may be right that you can't match more than one id at a time.

Comment: @Iceman while it may work, calling it 'the Rails way' is a bit of a stretch I think. This kind of specialist query is probably best tackled with AREL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why Phlip's answer does not work (as the OP said in a comment). If you can't make it work, here you have a more complicated and not efficient approach (it makes *number of player_ids + 1* queries):

```
player_ids = [6382,5635]

# All goal ids for player 6328 (first player in the array)
goal_ids = Goal.joins(:on_ice_skaters).where(on_ice_skaters: { player_id: player_ids[0] }).pluck(:id).uniq

player_ids.shift.each do |player_id|
  # Keep only goals in common for each other player
  goal_ids = goal_ids & Goal.joins(:on_ice_skaters).where(on_ice_skaters: { player_id: player_id }).pluck(:id).uniq
end

# Take these ids.
goals = Goal.where(id: goal_ids)
```

Comment: Ended up doing something similar to this.  I'll go back and try Phlip's answer again, maybe it was something on my end.  It certainly would be the cleanest.